# recording sound on 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, drivers, sound, dell

I am attempting to use the microphone port to send sound from a mixer out to ustream. My problem seems that the drivers are not working correctly. The machine can play sound just fine and everything else works perfectly.

This is a older Dell Optiplex GX60 with 4gigs of ram on board. This is a simple install for this purpose only so this machine should be able to handle what I am asking it to do for our podcast.

Is there something I can look at to see what the deal is, yes I check the sound panel to ensure the levels are up enough. Any ideas? Better sound drivers somewhere?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately we can not define the recording source for any recording application with the GNOME sound settings from the panel. We need to install [pavucontrol](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/pavucontrol) [image: Install pavucontrol] to do so.

**After** having started the recording from an application we will see the name off the application and the source from where it records in the *Recording* tab. There we may have to define the source `Monitor of <your soundcard>` to record:

[image]